# Convert digits to string with Java

Tags: java, string, numbers

Let's assume I have a function that prints 3-digit numbers as string (e.g. 301 -> Three Hundred One).

How can you use this function to print 9-digit numbers as string?

Comment: Rewrite your function again

Comment: in groups of 3? or you need to read full 9 digits numbers?

Comment: I need to read full 9 digit number @JordiCastilla

Comment: then....... rewrite your function as @NamanGala suggested....

Comment: Ask yourself, what is 301,000 in English words?  301,000,301?  3,010?  Seeing any patterns?  Good!  Use those patterns!

Comment: @JordiCastilla This was an interview question. They didn't expect me to change the previous function but write a new function which makes use of the 3-digit conversion.

Comment: @supaplex - Ermm ... whether it was an interview question, homework or just a puzzle, you will learn more if you try to solve it yourself ... and persist until you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you got the digit 301301301. In written text this will be: **Three Hundred One** Million **Three Hundred One** Thousand **Three Hundred One**

As you see you can pass 3 digits and get always the same result. Now just check, if you got 9 digits and then just pass 3 digits at a time and connect your result String with Million and Thousand.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
final int number = 301301301;
final int[] numbers = splitNumberInThree(301301301);
final String textNumber = numbersToText(numbers[0]) +
" Million " + numbersToText(numbers[1]) +
" Thousand " + numbersToText(numbers[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the 9-digits number on 3 parts. For each part apply method for 3-digits number. After each part insert word such as  " thousand" or " million".

For example, you have number 301.301.301.
After separating you have following:
 1. 301
 2. 301
 3. 301
Then you apply your method for this parts and obtain following:
1. Three Hundred One
 2. Three Hundred One
 3. Three Hundred One

After first part you should insert word "million". After second part you should insert " thousand". And after 3th part you don't insert word.
As a result you have: Three Hundred One million Three Hundred One Three Hundred One thousand Three Hundred One

Answer (score -1):

assume printNum is the function, and that it returns the string then:

```
int nineDigitsNum=999999999;
int temp=nineDigitsNum/1000000;
String text= "";
if(temp>0) text+=printNum(temp)+" milions";
int temp=(nineDigitsNum%1000000)/1000;
if(temp>0) text+=printNum(temp)+" thounsend"
int temp=(nineDigitsNum%1000);
text+=printNum(temp)
```